# Android Logic Based On Multiple Live Data Values

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I am using the Android data binding library to make reactive views with LiveData

I make a repo request for a list of jobs

```
var jobsRequest: LiveData<Resource<List<Job>>>
    = Transformations.switchMap(position) { repo.getJobsWithStatus(it) }
```

Then I have 3 more LiveData based on the above, like so

First, to check whether the request has completed

```
private val requestComplete: LiveData<Boolean>
    = Transformations.map(jobsRequest) { 
        it.status == Status.SUCCESS || it.status == Status.ERROR 
      }
```

Next, to transform to a list of jobs without the resource wrapper

```
var jobs: LiveData<List<Job>>
    = Transformations.map(jobsRequest) { it.data }
```

Lastly, to check if that job list is empty

```
val jobsEmpty: LiveData<Boolean>
    = Transformations.map(jobs) { (it ?: emptyList()).isEmpty() }
```

In the layout I want to show a loading spinner if the request has not completed and the jobs list is empty and need a variable in my view model to dictate this

I have tried the code below and, as expected, it does not work

```
val spinnerVisible: LiveData<Boolean>
    = Transformations.map(requestComplete) {
        !(requestComplete.value ?: false) && (jobsEmpty.value ?: true)
      }
```

What is the correct practice for having a LiveData variable based on the state of 2 others - I want to keep all logic in the view model, not in the activity or layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `jobsEmpty` observer needed? Seems like you could reuse the `jobs` one for it.

Anway, to your question:
For this there is a `MediatorLiveData`. It does what you need: it can merge multiple (in your case: 2) LiveData objects and can determine another livedata value based on that.

Some pseudo-code:

```
MediatorLiveData showSpinner = new MediatorLiveData<Boolean>()
showSpinner.addSource(jobsEmpty, { isEmpty ->
    if (isEmpty == true || requestComplete.value == true) {
       // We should show!
       showSpinner.value = true
    }
    // Remove observer again
    showSpinner.removeSource(jobsEmpty);
})
showSpinner.addSource(requestComplete, { isCompleted ->
    if (isCompleted == true && jobsEmpty == true) {
       // We should show!
       showSpinner.value = true
    }
    // Remove observer again
    showSpinner.removeSource(requestComplete);
})
return showSpinner
```

Note that you need to return the mediatorlivedata as result, as this is the object you are interested in for your layout.

Additionally, you can check the documentation on the `MediatorLiveData`, it has some more examples: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping for a more elegant solution really but this does make sense. Just to confirm, the line `showSpinner.removeSource(liveData1);` should be `showSpinner.removeSource(jobsEmpty);`? And if I want the value to continue to update should I omit this line?

Comment: Yeah correct, for the first one it should be `jobsEmpty` and for the second one it should be the `requestCompleted`. I wi update it in the answer :)

Comment: Yep, thats correct too! You can omit the `removeSource` line if you want to keep listening on it